# Trying to simply add a variable value to database

Tags: asp.net-core

New to asp.net core.I have a database (let's call in database123), with table Student. Student has 4 Columns, StudentId, StudentNameName, StudentGender and CreatedUtc.

No probs adding data via razor page to database. But I want the CreatedUtc value to be inserted into the database, not via the view, but via the controller (it is the date the record was created and should come from DateTime.Now.ToString or something similar.

I am having trouble figuring out where and how to code this into the Create.cshtml.cs controller. I assume it needs to be entered into the public async Task OnPostAsync().

**Currently I have this**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
  {
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
   return Page();
   }
    MessageVar += $" Server time  { DateTime.Now.ToString() }"; // Get Date and Time
    _context.Student.Add(Student);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

**In the CreateModel area above, I have this:-**

```
   public string MessageVar { get; private set; } = "Local Server Time: ";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know it is probably really simple, but just having trouble finding it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving your student, set the time.

```
student.createdutc = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Comment: Hi JayBird, I might have missed something but  I am getting an error. " Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "System.DateTime" "

Comment: I've updated my answer, don't need to make the date a string.

Comment: Sorry, CreatedUtc is a DateTime field in the model. YOu gave me an idea, I just entered this Student.CreatedUtc = DateTime.Now;, no error. I am testing now. THanks.

Comment: One further update. Since your field is named createdutc, you could assign it the current Utc date using UtcNow

Comment: Awesome, JayBird, thankyou so much mate, that worked a treat!!! I knew it would be simple, didn't know it would be that simple. Thankyou so much mate. ...